# "{" missing function header (old style format list) - expected a declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm really really new to C++ and this is my first program on Visual Studio 2015, It shows me 2 errors:

**"{" missing function header (old style format list)
 expected a declaration**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main();
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main()` remove `;` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int main()` remove ; at the end.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(); // this ';' is giving problem remove it.
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";  // use std::cout
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next error: it is called `std::cout`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Right, but in some compiler it may run with it also. thanks I will add this to the answer as well.

Comment: A non standards-compliant one maybe?

Comment: @juanchopanza, i added that point too in the answer.